# If values in one row match the criteria, compare it with another value for a match and count

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Please check both links.

[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePNv1.png)
[Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xcn24.png)

What I'm trying to accomplish is...

On Sheet1,  check each row for A="MSP1", B="AZNG", E=blank and F1="FULL"  then check column D in Sheet1 against column C in Sheet2.

If there is a partial match, such as in the example "V210363" and 
"AZNG V210363" then count it as 1 for each entry that fits this criteria.

**Note,** it's not an exact match as the number is preceded by a 4 letter string  and a space.

Comment: Rajesh S, I'm confused. Why did you edit my question to ask a question completely different than what I was asking? I wasn't asking about specific cells like A1 etc that you changed, I was talking about the entire column in each row.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the function below in **Sheet1**. The function will return *TRUE* if all conditions are matched, otherwise *FALSE*.

```
=IF(AND(A2="MSP1",B2="AZNG",E2="",F2="FULL"),NOT(ISERROR(MATCH("*"&D2&"*",Sheet2!$C$2:$C$15,0))))
```

The formula checks A, B, E, F columns first and if conditions fulfilled then checks if searching D in Sheet2's C will return an error or not.

Comment: An admin edited my question which may have caused confusion, but I'm looking for a formula that checks every row, not just one.

Comment: @MathewBauler I updated the formula to look Sheet2!C2:C15 range. You can use joker characters like * and ? while make text searching.